# Percentage of Count values in MS-Access

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access table where I can count the occurrences of a column however in addition to count I need the percentage of these occurrences

My table has two columns. Month, Subjects. I can retrieve the count such a Subject A has 10 occurrences, Subject B has 15 and so on in my table.

Have tried these two codes but gives a syntax error
Code 1

```
SELECT Subjects, 
COUNT(Subjects.Subject) AS CountOfSubject,
(SELECT COUNT(Subjects.Subject))/(SELECT SUM(Subjects.CountofSubject)))    AS PercentofSubject
FROM Subjects 
GROUP BY Subject;
```

Code 2

```
SELECT Subjects, 
COUNT(Subjects.Subject) AS CountOfSubject,
(SELECT AVG(Subjects.CountofSubject)) AS PercentofSubject
FROM Subjects
GROUP BY Subject;
```

However I need additional column where I can show percentage value of these subject occurrences. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big problem I see with your code is that you are not normalizing the counts properly by using a complete subquery.  Try this version:

```
SELECT
    Subject,
    COUNT(*) AS CountOfSubject,
    100.0 * COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Subjects) AS PercentOfSubject
FROM Subjects 
GROUP BY Subject;
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Work like a charm.